# converting pandas data frame to dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am using the following code to convert a Dataframe whose structure is as follows

[image]

```
dummy= df.set_index(['location']).T.to_dict('list')
for key,value in dummy.items():
    dummy[key] = tuple(value)
```

to obtain a dictionary of tuples
{loc_1:(35.99,-81.44),loc_2:(22.55,-108.5)}

Question
1. Will the order be preserved as lat-long? (Is there a chance the first tuple can turn out to be (-81.44,35.99)?

Question 2. Is there a better(faster/elegant)way of doing the above

Comment: Thanks Victor that answers my second question. It will be great if someone can help me with the first question.

Comment: The order will be preserved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a comprehension and `itertuples`

```
dict([(t.location, (t.lat, t.long)) for t in df.itertuples()])

{loc_1: (35.99, -81.44), loc_2: (22.55, -108.5)}
```